# Do superuser things with normal user

Tags: ssh, sudo, root

**EDIT**

Read answer of janos below.

It's more use SSH-keys to access a root directly.

---

I want to secure the SSH access to my server. One thing I read everywhere is to disable the root user login.

To still have access via SSH I created another user via `sudo adduser john`

How can I still do root things with this account?

`sudo command` asks for a password of the user but gives `john not in sudoer file. Action will be reported`. When I use `su` I log in as root which I'm going to disable.

How can I stil do `root` things with the normal account `john`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit `/etc/sudoers` **using the `visudo` command** and add a line for the user `john`.

Probably you will want to add a line like `john ALL=(ALL) ALL`. Then you can issue commands using `sudo` (running as `john`) and, if desired, disable the root user, or at least use a very strong password for it - this would be my choice.

Besides, most versions of SSH should have root login disabled by default; that means **you can't login as root over SSH**, but you can SSH as user and then become root with `su`. If in doubt, check the `PermitRootLogin` statement in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. From the manpage:

```
   PermitRootLogin
          Specifies whether root can log in using  ssh(1).   The  argument  must  be
          ``yes'',  ``without-password'',  ``forced-commands-only'', or ``no''.  The
          default is ``yes''.
```

Comment: At least Debian systems allow root login per default. If you comment the `PermitRootLogin yes` line, root login will be *enabled*.

Comment: Indeed. Fixing my answer

Answer (score 1):

- If you're already logged in as root, using `sudo` is pointless.
- To allow `john` to gain root privileges, it suffices to execute

  ```
  usermod john -G admin
  ```

  in a Ubuntu default installation, since it adds `john` to the group `admin` (implies root privileges).

  For other distributions, you can consult `/etc/sudoers` for a group with this privilege.
- Disabling `root` is nice, but a user with root privileges can still do anything he wants.

  Not logging in as `root` only has advantages if you do it for any of the following reasons:

  - Preventing *accidental* changes to your system (`rm -rf /`, malware, etc.).

    `sudo su` lets you become root once you logged in as a user with root privileges.
  - You use something else than the user password to authenticate (e.g., private keys).

    In this case, the `sudo` command still requires the user password, so it adds an extra layer of security (unattended laptop, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that permitting root login with ssh is less insecure than the practice of using `su root`. This post on the Debian mailing list by Simon Kirby explains it very well:

http://lists.debian.org/debian-security/2002/06/msg00418.html

Permitting root login with ssh keys only might be more secure than the practice of `sudo`, but I'm not an expert. For what it's worth, the setting for that is:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Comment: It's not an answer on my question. The problem I described is not an issue anymore. Ty

Comment: You should mark @Renan's answer as "the answer". My "answer" was meant as additional important note.

Answer (score 0):

Disable root login via ssh is smart.  But there is no reason not to su to root once you login. Make sure both accounts have strong passwords and install fail2ban to prevent forest fires - sorry, crack attempts.

Comment: But when I disable root login via SSH I cannot use #su? Or am I wrong? If I can do #su with root access disabled than i don't have a problem.

Comment: You can still use `su`. Disabling ssh login for root has no effect on becoming root with `su` after a successful ssh login as normal user.

Comment: You are wrong; you can't **login** as root, but you can **login as user** and become root using `su`.